# GWT CSS problem

Tags: html, css, gwt

I have a menu on the top of a page and when I get the sub menu, it is collapsing with the existing html on the host page

Menu when not yet clicked
[image]

Menu when menu item clicked
[image]

Just notice the blue line is comming on the top of the sub menu

The menu is found in a div

can someone helps??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what I understand is your sub menu doesn't come on top of the blue bar, but instead, is seen under it. That could be the problem, but need not be.

You'll need to find the CSS class used for the sub menu (something like firebug on Firefox will help you here, or IE developer toolbar in IE), and then check the following:

1) If there's a background colour set anywhere. If not, add it
2) the z-index of the sub menu. If its no >= 1, then increase it. If there is no z-index, try adding it to 1 or 10. Check the z-index of the logo image. If there is no z-index, don't worry about it. If there is, you need to make sure that the z-index of the submenu is greater than the z-index of the logo image.

Comment: Ya, this is the problem, I will try your solution

Answer (score 0):

This is because the z-index of blue line is more than the z-index of menu.So through the css if you increase the z-index of menu than the blue line then your problem can be solved.